# MongoDB 3.4.23 featureCompatibilityVersion was set to 3.2 after master node crash

Tags: mongodb

Master node of 3-nodes replicaset gone OOM and was killed by kernel. After it was restarted and master role was retaken, featureCompatibilityVersion was set to 3.2 instead of 3.4 but there's no trace of that change in logs. That caused some issues on client side until i manually switched it back to 3.4.

It's a clean installation of 3.4.23, no upgrades was made on this replicaset.

Is it normal behaviour or some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug but, since 3.4 server has passed its end of life, your only real solution is to upgrade to a supported version (3.6+ as of this writing).

Answer (score 0):

seems bug, if it's new installation. You need to set featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.4 or add in start script to avoid any application error.

**Recommendation**: 3.4 has passed it's end of life and 3.6 have end of life in another 6 months. Please take reference of below link. So better plan to upgrade your mongodb server to 4.0

https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy